# If the code with Debugger statement Javascript gets deployed on Production how much of security concern does it pose?

Tags: javascript, security, javascript-debugger

Sometimes to debug Javascript code the `debugger;` statement is written in code.

1. What are Security Concerns in javascript?
2. Is it possible to Encrypt
   script code?

Comment: Well. It happened with me once (code with debugger statement pushed to production env). Can't think of any security ramifications. And Ua's debugger works only when your dev tools are open...btw what do u mean by Encrypting script code is possible?

Comment: Client-side code never had any security in the first place.

Comment: @bhavya_w : I want to hide my script logic or atleast make it difficult to understand for naive user. So is there any technique I can use to encrypt my code logic?

Comment: look into google closure compiler or YUIcompresser...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally a good idea to remove commands like this and `console` from production data. I don't think it's particularly a security concern however.

You could use something like a precommit git hook or a [grunt task](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-search) to check for the keywords you don't want appearing before deployment.

If you want to minify/obfuscate your code you can use something like [uglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) for which there is also a [grunt plugin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) for that too.